Anime where robots resembling the machines from Nier: Automata attack a city and begin killing everyone
A few days ago, YouTube recommended a video to me. Unfortunately, the video seems to have been deleted or hidden by the creator.
It included a scene from an anime where a city was under attack by giant robots. Two girls were running for their lives when one was gruesomely and painfully killed. The other girl, who was nearby, managed to escape.
The robots, much larger than humans and resembling the machines from Nier: Automata, laid waste to the city. Houses burned, and everything lay in ruins.  They were also killing everyone in the city. (Here's a photo of the machines from Nier: Automata for reference.)

I've searched for this anime on Google and YouTube, but I haven't been able to find it.
Does anyone recognize the anime from this description?
